# I need to add more than 1000 user to table AspNet User

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, identity, code-first

I need to add more than 1000 users to AspNetUser table ,when i added some users ,those users not able to login, because the password not hash .

Is there any services in mvc to upload excel file and hash password before added to database ? . Or can i change usermanager policy  to allow user login with out hash password

Comment: Asking for off- site resources, utilities, etc is off topic for SO. As far as storing passwords un-hashed, DON'T.

Comment: You need to create a user account for those users that cannot login.  This is not a hash issue.  The code need a user login.

Comment: Dear jdweng, thank you for your answer . i have user login and registration there is no issue from this side  , i tried to add users by registration, it's login  . but how i can registe more than 1000 users or more . I need to some help or service import those user to aspnetuser table .

Comment: there is one solution . i need to help for my scenario . i want add users manually to database and  when those users try login if the user password have hash login if not redirect to reset password .

Comment: if(model.Password != ............... ?)
            {

            } else
            {
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);